# How to read store values outside of the render tree in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-redux

I am learning flutter and trying to integrate with redux for store managment.

All the examples I see the store is accessed in the render part of the widget, for example like so:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
  child: StoreConnector<AppState, List<Photo>>(
        converter: (store) => store.state.photos,
        builder: (_, photos) {
          return GridView.builder(
            itemCount: photos.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final photoUrl = photos[index].portrait;
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child: new Image.network(
                  photoUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              );
            },
            gridDelegate:                                    
            // .......
```

but how to get a value from the store in initState, and detect if that value changes, for example? And can I have a listener for certain value outside the render tree?

Thank you.

Edit for clarity, what I am looking for is some Flutter equivalent of react's useSelector being able to get the change in value in useEffect

Edit: I was thinking that an option (though not the answer to the question) could be to pass the values from the parent and then use didChangeDependencies() in the child

Comment: If you already familiar with react's hooks why don't use riverpod hooks, It has useEffect function and a value selector method.

Comment: Thank you @MohammedAlfateh , I spent countless hours to have the Redux working, I'd die if I change now. Is that instead of Redux or a complement?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know much about the  react's useSelector and redux but **In Flutter you can Pass Function as a Paramter which help to change the value across different widgets.**

**Example**

```
  class MainClass extends StatefulWidget {
  MainClass({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainClassState createState() => _MainClassState();
}

class _MainClassState extends State<MainClass> {
  int value = 0;

  changeValue(int newValue) {
    setState(() {
      value = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('value is $value');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          InnerClass2(
            value: value,
          ),
          InnerClass(
            changeValue: changeValue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  Function changeValue;

  InnerClass({@required this.changeValue, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InnerClassState createState() => _InnerClassState();
}

class _InnerClassState extends State<InnerClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          widget.changeValue(2);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerClass2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  const InnerClass2({@required this.value, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(value.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes @MohammadRaza , but that is a different case. I need to do stuff when redux store changes.